# Extracting value from jmeter post request

Tags: jmeter

I want to extract value of the parameter sent through post request in jmeter.
I know the use of regular expression for extracting response value or request URL but here I would like to extract the value of post request.

I've been thorough [how to extract value from request in Jmeter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31127129/how-to-extract-value-from-request-in-jmeter) but it didn't worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I added a Beanshell PostProcessor in my http request with following code.

```
import org.apache.jmeter.config.Argument;
import org.apache.jmeter.config.Arguments;

Arguments argz = ctx.getCurrentSampler().getArguments();
for (int i = 0; i < argz.getArgumentCount(); i++) {
   Argument arg = argz.getArgument(i);
    String a = arg.getValue();
    vars.put("EMAIL",a);
 }
```

Explanation: I get a my request as a json and put it in EMAIL. Now I can use EMAIL as a variable in my other request.

Then, I added a jp@gc Json Path Extractor and I applied it to a Jmeter Varaible.
Now, Email will be used as variable, which contains my json request and I can extract using jsonPath Extractor.

Comment: https://kishorsharma69.wordpress.com/2016/10/03/absolute-directory-path-for-jmx-file-jmeter/ for more details.

Answer (score 2):

Not sure why do you need it as given you sending "something" you should already have that "something" hence you don't need to extract it, however here you go:

In order to save 1st parameter value (or the whole post data if you use "Body Data" mode):

1. Add [Beanshell PostProcessor](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#BeanShell_PostProcessor) as a child of the HTTP Request.
2. Put the following code into the PostProcessor's "Script" area:

   ```
   String request = ctx.getCurrentSampler().getArguments().getArgument(0).getValue();
   vars.put("request", request);
   ```

You will be able to access extracted value as `${request}` where required.

Clarifications:

- `ctx` - shorthand for [JMeterContext](https://jmeter.apache.org/api/org/apache/jmeter/threads/JMeterContext.html) class instance
- `getCurrentSampler()` - in case of HTTP Request sampler stands for [HTTPSamplerProxy](https://jmeter.apache.org/api/org/apache/jmeter/protocol/http/sampler/HTTPSamplerProxy.html)

See [How to Use BeanShell: JMeter's Favorite Built-in Component](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/queen-jmeters-built-componentshow-use-beanshell) guide for more information on using JMeter and Java API from Beanshell test elements in your JMeter test.

Answer (score 0):

An easy way to do this is using the JSON Path Extractor.

There are just
For the example you gave
`{ "data" : {   "name" : "john_doe", } }`

'Variable Name: YourNewVar'
'JSON Path: $.data.name'
Should work, but you may need to do some experimenting.

You may want to add a "debug sampler" (its one of the standard samplers) and put in its title $YourNewVar so you can see what is being extracted.

Beanshell and "Regular Expression Extractor" will work, of course, but may be a little harder to use if you are not familiar with them.